# Using multiple renderers simultaneously in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

If a part of the graphics do not change, such as the background, while other parts of it change frequently, would it be more efficient to overlay separate transparent GLSurfaceViews and Renderers, one for the static parts and another for the changing parts, so that the unchanging parts do not have to be constantly redrawn?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to use more than one GLSurfaceView at a time, but someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If that's the case, is there any way to work around constantly redrawing static elements?

Comment: You can work with the stencil buffer.. Update the stencil, draw the static part only one time.

Comment: You're right Tim, its not possible using multiple GLSurfaceViews at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple GLSurfaceViews are possible.

Separate GLSurfaceViews is not a nice idea if:
1]there are a lot of overlapping between the surfaces(Wasing video memory)
2]If multiple GLSurafces needs to be updated simultaneously manytimes(GL context switching leads to horribe performance.)

If these 2 cases are not applicable for you, then multiple GLSuraceViews as definitely an option.